# How to display search type Android keyboard in react-native

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

I've got a text input in my app which I use as a search bar and I know that Android has an API to display a search type keyboard and I'm wondering how I can use it in react-native.

I've looked [in the react-native text input documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) but didn't find anything for that type of keyboard in Android.

[image: my screen]

Anyone knows which type of keyboard I can use in text input to achieve wanted result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [returnKeyType](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#returnkeytype) and [keyboardType](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype)